# simple_form_for fails with "can't write unknown attribute `builder'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a Post model with a one-to-many relationship with a Comments model. I'm using simple_form in a partial to create some quick forms (specifically, for the comment model) for my user interface:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, Comment.new) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :comment, :input_html => {:rows => 20, :class => 'span12'} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, Rails fails with the following error: `can't write unknown attribute 'builder'` and the stack trace pointing to the first line (`<%= simple_form_for(@post, Comment.new) do |f| %>`).

Where does this builder attribute come from and how can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess you use `nested resources`. If so, AFAIK, you should pass an array to `simple_form_for` method as first parameter (responsible for setting the proper form URL):

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```

Comment: That worked! I knew it had to be something simple I was missing. Thanks!